# Fortran 66 if() go to

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to understand a code from a article that I have to read for a project I'm working for, and it's written Fortran 66.

I don't understand the way it will work. I tried to write a similar code with same structures but it doesn't work. It's something similar to this

```
   if(conditional.1)go to 20
       *some code*
       go to 30
20 if (conditional.2)
       *some code*
       go to 30

30 continue
```

If the `conditional.1` is True it will go to `20` or it will go to `30`

And if it's false it will go to`20`?

It would be similar to this?:

```
if(conditional.1)then
    *some code*
end if

if(conditional.2)then
    *some code*
end if
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please do not show "something similar", show some actual code. See [mcve] and [ask]. `(conditional.1)` is NOT valid Fortran syntax.

Comment: Also be aware that `end if` is not legal in Fortran 66, although there is absolutely no reason to follow that historical standard in this century.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of spaghetti code that you get from overusing GOTO and from the lack of better structures in FORTRAN 66. You can visualize the evolution using a flowchart.

If conditional 1 is `.true.` then you *skip* the first `*some code*`. So I believe it would be

```
   if (.not. conditional.1) then
       *some code 1*
   else if (conditional.2) then
       *some code 2*
   end if
```

in Fortran 77 and later.

Comment: Depending on exactly what is being done Select Case might be a fit as well (Fortran 90 and later)